Packet sniffing of IOT camera's UDP stream to regenerate video
I really want to figure this out but my dumb brain cannot figure it out. Please help me!
I am utilizing a EOUP Wi-Fi adapter to sniff the packet between TAPO C210 indoor camera and Spectrum router. I captured handshake and traffics(Airodump-ng) by de-authentication attack(Airreplay-ng). I decrypted the traffic using captured handshake and WPA-password. However, i encountered the issue to generate video stream by gathering the captured traffic. When i decoded traffic from UDP into RTP or M2PT, it does not recognize as the video format. I have three theories on failing these attempt. Is my assumption valid?

I assume it is because the AES-128 encryption from the initial setup.
Header of the format does not match
Packet segmentation loss from sniffing on wi-fi adapter

Is there way to re-generate the video footage by packet sniffing technique or other techniques?
Handshake
Decode as RTP
Captured UDP stream
